# A question related to Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Try to compute $u(t)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\sin tx\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $ v(t)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\cos tx\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to constuct a system of linear equations and attempted to use Euler formula for complex numbers , but still I failed to solve the question. Now I am trying to use the principle of integration by parts to find the relationship.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to constuct a system of linear equations and attempted to use Euler formula for complex numbers , but still I failed to solve the question.

Comment: Use the substitution $u^2=x$, then it's Gaussian integral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that, by Euler formula,

$$v(t) + iu(t) = \int_0^\infty \text e^{-(1-it)x}\frac{\text dx}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Using the substitution $\xi^2 = (1-it)x$, and so

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-it}} \text d\xi = \frac{\text dx}{\sqrt{x}}$$

we get a scaled Gaussian integral

$$ v(t) + iu(t) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-it}} \int_0^\infty \text e^{-\xi^2}\text d\xi = \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{1-it}} $$

and so

$$ u(t) = \mathcal{Im}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{1-it}}\right) = \sqrt[4]{\frac{\pi^2}{1+t^2}}\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\arg\left(\frac{1}{1-it}\right)\right) \\ v(t) = \mathcal{Re}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{1-it}}\right) = \sqrt[4]{\frac{\pi^2}{1+t^2}}\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\arg\left(\frac{1}{1-it}\right)\right)$$

You might be able to express $\sin\frac{1}{2}\arg$ and $\cos\frac{1}{2}\arg$ in a radical form, but I'm not sure if it's worth it.

Comment: It seems that you missed a minus in the exponent, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @ykuan Good catch, it's fixed now.